# Step through pandas dataframe based on keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
      A1  A1_step  A1_step_n  LB7  dF
0  40000      500          2    4   2
1  60000      300          3    6   7
```

I want to use the columns that have the `step` and `step_n` keywords to "step" (iterate) through the rows of the dataframe with the specified step size. So in the above sample dataframe I would like to iterate through the 40000 row of the `A1` column twice with steps of 500 and three times with steps of 300 for the row with 60000. Ultimately, I'd like the dataframe to look like

```
In [98]: df2
Out[98]:
      A1    LB7  dF
0  40000      4   2
1  40500      4   2
2  60000      6   7
3  60300      6   7
4  60600      6   7
```

where the values for `LB7` and `dF` are carried through and the "step" columns are no longer needed.

I've tried looping through the columns trying to pluck out which columns get iterated through and looping through those loops to add to the dataframe, but it gets very messy very quickly and I'm hoping someone here can lead me down a better path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows and manually build your dataframe like this:

```
dfs = []
col_step = df.columns.str.extract('(.*\_step$)', expand=False).dropna()[0]
col_step_n = df.columns.str.extract('(.*\_step\_n$)', expand=False).dropna()[0]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row['A1']
    steps = row[col_step_n]
    size = row[col_step]
    stop = start + size * (steps)
    df_cur = pd.DataFrame({'A1': np.arange(start, stop, size), 'LB7':row['LB7'], 'dF':row['dF']})
    dfs.append(df_cur)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Output

```
print(df_final)
      A1  LB7  dF
0  40000    4   2
1  40500    4   2
2  60000    6   7
3  60300    6   7
4  60600    6   7
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I should have added though that I don't know the column names a priori, just that there are some with "_step" and "_step_n" appended to the names. That said, I think I should be able to take it from here. I will keep the question open for a little while in case someone else (or yourself) gives a solution that involves finding which columns have "_step" and "_step_n" first.

Comment: You should be able to use a regular expression to extract the column string name. The above fix should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = df.values
reps = np.arange(len(v)).repeat(v[:, 2])
a1 = np.concatenate([np.arange(a, a + b * c, b) for a, b, c in v[:, :3]])[:, None]
v1 = v[:, 3:][reps]
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([a1, v1]), columns=['A1', 'LB7', 'dF'])


      A1  LB7  dF
0  40000    4   2
1  40500    4   2
2  60000    6   7
3  60300    6   7
4  60600    6   7
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share the answer I ultimately went with as it demonstrates the level of generality I was looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

dfs = []
step_cols = [col[:-7] for col in df.columns if '_step_n' in col]
const_cols = ([col + '_step' for col in step_cols] + step_cols +
              [col + '_step_n' for col in step_cols])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ranges = []
    for col in step_cols:
        start = row[col]
        stop = row[col] + row[col + '_step'] * row[col + '_step_n']
        step = row[col + '_step']
        ranges.append(list(range(start, stop, step)))
    combos = list(product(*ranges))
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(
        {**{k: v for k, v in zip(step_cols, zip(*combos))},
         **df.drop(const_cols, axis=1).iloc[i].to_dict()}))

df2 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

So that if the original `df` is

```
In [226]: df
Out[226]:
      A1  LB7  dF  A1_step_n  A1_step
0  40000    4   2          2      500
1  60000    6   7          3      300
```

The resulting `df2` is

```
In [227]: df2
Out[227]:
      A1  LB7  dF
0  40000    4   2
1  40500    4   2
2  60000    6   7
3  60300    6   7
4  60600    6   7
```

---

This has the added benefit that tacking on "_step" and "_step_n" to additional column names allows you to iterate through the cartesian product. E.g. if original `df` is

```
In [230]: df
Out[230]:
    A1  LB7  dF  A1_step_n  A1_step  dF_step_n  dF_step
0  100    5  15          4       50          2        7
1  200    8  30          3       30          3        4
```

The resulting `df2` will iterate through both `A1` and `dF`

```
In [231]: df2
Out[231]:
     A1  LB7  dF
0   100    5  15
1   100    5  22
2   150    5  15
3   150    5  22
4   200    5  15
5   200    5  22
6   250    5  15
7   250    5  22
8   200    8  30
9   200    8  34
10  200    8  38
11  230    8  30
12  230    8  34
13  230    8  38
14  260    8  30
15  260    8  34
16  260    8  38
```